# How to extend my main Linux partition?

Tags: partition, fdisk, gparted

I am using PopOS 20.10 and Windows 10 dual boot on laptop and I want to upgrade capacity of partition `sda6`.

[image]

`/dev/sda6` is a single Linux partition and `/dev/sda8` partition (recently created), both are Linux filesystems.

How to merge `sda6` and `sda8` without losing data from `sda6`?

Both partitions are along side each other.

How to merge both in single partition without losing data?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to simply use the second partition for example as a `/home` partition (or just as some "data" partition mounted to `/mnt/data` or something similar). More about moving `/home` to a separate partition [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206/how-can-i-move-the-home-directory-to-a-separate-partition).

Other option would be to remove the `sda8` partition and use GParted to move and resize the `sda6` partition (*Partition → Resize/Move*). This can't be done from a running system, you'll need to use a LiveCD. (Make sure to backup your data first. Also note the move/resize operation can take a lot of time, moving ~150 GiB won't be fast.)

Comment: thanks using live USB for partitioning worked it took time to copy all data but partitions were merged without corrupting any data